Can I switch my Apple Watch from GPS only to cellular?
I have an  Apple Watch which I purchased over the summer. (series 9). It only has GPS. I would now like to switch to cellular.
Is there a way I can upgrade my watch that doesn't have cellular to have that feature?

Simple answer - no. You need to purchase a new Apple Watch should you require cellular data service. There is no upgrade offered by Apple.
Apple Discussion here.
The cellular model Apple Watch 10 weighs slightly less than the GPS model, presumably since more of the dense case needs to be carved away to allow for the cellular antenna to be placed inside the same  size shell casing.

Interesting info, bmike.
